# Generating xml sitemap for dynamic routes in Nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, seo, nuxt.js, xml-sitemap

So I'm currently implementing sitemaps for a website that features multiple store fronts.

I used [nuxt sitemap module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module) to generate a `/sitemap/sitemap.xml` file for the static pages, like homepage, terms and conditions and privacy policy.

Now the website also contains dynamic routes for every store front, for example: `mysite.com/store1` & `mysite.com/store2`

The current task is to create a `/sitemap.xml` for each store, so the end result is something like: `mysite.com/store1/sitemap.xml`

This sitemap will contain everything related to the store, including dynamic subroutes of each product.

I'm currently not aware of any possible way to do this, and I've searched a lot but I couldn't find anything on this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a sitemap index as follows:

```
{
  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://example.com',
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    sitemaps: [
      {
        path: '/sitemap/sitemap.xml',
      },
      {
        path: '/store1/sitemap.xml',
        exclude: ['/**'],
        routes: () => { /* return array of url for store #1 */ }
      },
      {
        path: '/store2/sitemap.xml',
        exclude: ['/**'],
        routes: () => { /* return array of url for store #2 */ }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You will have this result:

- /sitemap.xml  => the sitemap index (the entry point for crawlers)
- /sitemap/sitemap.xml  => all static routes
- /store1/sitemap.xml  => only dynamic routes for store #1
- /store2/sitemap.xml  => only dynamic routes for store #2

Comment: Looks great, but the main issue is, the number of store entries (store1, store2, myStore3...) is unknown and they increase/decrease frequently, with different random names as well. @Nicolas Pennec

Comment: Be sure to add this: exclude: ['/**'], because static routes are merged with dynamic paths...

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it worked for me

```
  sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    hostname: process.env.BASE_URL,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    gzip: true,
    generate: false,
    sitemaps: [
      {
        path: '/sitemap/sitemap.xml',
      },
      {
        path: '/store1/sitemap.xml',
        exclude: [],
        routes: async () => {
            let apiUrl = 'your site url' // or API url
            const { data } = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}store1`)
            return data.data.map(v => `/${v.id}`)
          }
      },
      {
        path: '/store2/sitemap.xml',
        exclude: [],
        routes: async () => {
            let apiUrl = 'your site url' // or API url
            const { data } = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}store2`)
            return data.data.map(v => `/${v.id}`)
          }
      },
      {
        path: '/store3/sitemap.xml',
        exclude: [],
        routes: async () => {
            let apiUrl = 'your site url' // or API url
            const { data } = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}store3`)
            return data.data.map(v => `/${v.id}`)
          }
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Jimmy Kiarie 
but what if I don't know how many stores are there and what their names are?
There are lots of stores with dynamic naming (not store1, store2, store3 - this was an example sorry)